# Two-dimensional array created from Array() produces weird behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays

If a create a two-dimensional array like this:

```js
let a = [
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
]
```

And then change the value of the first element, everything goes as expected:

```js
a[0][0] = 1

/*
Output: 

[
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
]
*/
```

but if i create an array like this:

```js
let b = Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(0))
```

And try to change the first element like i did before, all the first elements of second array will be changed:

```js
a[0][0] = 1

/*
Output:

let b = [
  [1, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0],
]
*/
```

Could someone explain to me why this happens? I'm not trying to do anything in particular, just trying to better understand how things work in javascript

Comment: `fill` takes a constant value. an array has the same object reference by taken with `fill`.

Comment: put that code into a snippet and look at the console.log  - it shows the new array is one element, followed by 2 references to it.